# Google Analytics Cookie conflicts

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, web-analytics

My website uses quite a popular booking engine (say popularibe.com) which is used by many other my competitor websites. This booking engine uses google classic analytics code across all the booking engine pages for their own tracking purposes.

So, normally when a visitor comes to my website, they already have cookies (classic cookies) written for this particular booking engines' sub domain name (say sub.popularibe.com).

I have always used "auto" as my cookieDomain field and now I see that 2 different cookie IDs, one for popularibe.com (passed from my website say id1) and other for sub.popularibe.com (brought by visitor from other website, say id2). So, two different client Ids.

The biggest issue I am facing is, all my pageview hits goes to one client Id (id1) and all the transaction hits goes to the other client Id (id2). This dynamites all my Analytics data :(

Could you please suggest a solution for this? If I switch off auto in cookieDomain, will this fix?

Thanks

Comment: If the payment provider is on another domain not under your control then your GA account will track nothing on that domain, cookieDomain nonwithstanding. Cookies are domain specific, so js code on your website won't even be able to read the cookie from sub.popularibe.com.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I have my tracking codes on this payment provider domain (sun.popularibe.com), my _ga cookie is written on popularibe.com whereas its classic cookies and another _ga cookie is written on sub.popularibe.com. Thank you @EikePierstorff